# Return only results that match more than 2 conditions

Tags: sql

How do I only return results if more than two values from a list are found?

For example, if they don't have at least three of the following codes attached to their account then don't include them:

```
I13.0
I13.2
I20.0
I20.1
I20.8
I20.9
I21.01
I21.02
I21.09
I21.11
I21.19
I21.21
I21.29
I21.3
I21.4
I21.9
I21.A1
I21.A9
I22.0
```

Do I just need to put `having count(distinct PROB.ICD10DiagnosisCode) > 2` after the group statement? I am getting results but I want to make sure I am not taking the long way around the bus.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PER.ID AS PatientID,
    IORG.OrganizationMRN AS PatientMRN
FROM works..Problem PROB (nolock)
JOIN works..Problem_Encounter PROBENC ON PROB.ID = PROBENC.ProblemID
JOIN works..Encounter ENC ON PROBENC.EncounterID = ENC.ID
JOIN works..patient_member PM ON ENC.PatientID = PM.ID
JOIN works..Document ON Document.EncounterID = ENC.ID
JOIN works..DocumentEvent
    ON Document.documentid = DocumentEvent.documentid
JOIN works..Person PER ON Document.PatientID = PER.ID
JOIN works..Patient_Iorg IORG
    ON PER.ID = IORG.PersonID and IORG.InternalOrganization = 3
WHERE PROB.ProblemStatusDE IN (9) 
    AND PROB.RecordedDTTM > DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())
    AND PROB.ICD10DiagnosisCode IN
    (
        SELECT ICD10DiagnosisCode
        FROM CVCReports.dbo.rptPETEligibleICD10
    )
    AND PM.IsDeceasedFLAG = 'N'
    AND DocumentEvent.documenteventde NOT IN (18)
    AND Document.Status LIKE 'Final%' 
    AND Document.DocumentTypeDE NOT IN (288)
    AND ENC.DTTM > DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())
GROUP BY OrganizationMrn, PER.ID
having count(distinct PROB.ICD10DiagnosisCode) > 2
```

Comment: Why did you change your condition for ICD10DiagnosisCode  from a JOIN to an IN statement?

Comment: Yeah, it's likely that you want to join to the eligible ICD10 table. Doing that allow you to use `having` that way.

Comment: This is part of an application. The user is allowed to add the ICD10DiagnosisCode's they want into that table. I guess the question is how do I include the codes in that table as part of having count?